# Missing data from google finance API

Tags: pandas, google-finance

I'm using pandas to download the daily closing price of 'AMZN'. Since yahoo finance is down recently(Probably because they changed URL?), I wish to use google finance instead. However, I found that some data was missing when using google. For example, I found that there's no data on 04/01/2010.
Anybody have any ideas on that?

Comment: Please provide more details and a dummy code...

Comment: Provide code. Also, Yahoo Finance old servers (ichart) are down permanently.